# Is it possible to get the contact point of a laser sensor?

Tags: gazebo-sensor

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

is there a simple solution for getting the coordinates on which the rays of a sensor hit a target?
At the moment I calculate the points myself by using the sensor pose, the start and end angles and the samples, but I think there has to be an easier way to do that...

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3945/is-it-possible-to-get-the-contact-point-of-a-laser-sensor?/) by [Chris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/269/chris/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 67 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

That's the easiest way. Gazebo mimics the output from laser range finders, which is typically angle and range readings.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/269/chris/) on 2013-07-31**:
Ok, thank you!